# Sum of digits 11?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 4 digit numbers have sum of digits 11?

The way I was solving for whole number solutions through partitioning was `n+r-1Cr-1` but here they are digits so must be in the range of [0,9] where the first digit cannot be zero so [1,9]

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your initial thoughts are good.  This problem is as you say equivalent to finding the number of non-negative integer solutions to the system:

$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=11\\1\leq x_1\leq 9\\ 0\leq x_2\leq 9\\ 0\leq x_3\leq 9\\ 0\leq x_4\leq 9\end{cases}$

Let us change variables, where $y_1=x_1-1$ and $y_i=x_i$ for the others.

$\begin{cases} y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=10\\0\leq y_1\leq 8\\ 0\leq y_2\leq 9\\ 0\leq y_3\leq 9\\ 0\leq y_4\leq 9\end{cases}$

Now, try to approach via inclusion-exclusion based on which of the upperbounds on the inequalities is violated.  Fortunately, this is relatively short since it is impossible to have two upper bounds violated simultaneously in this scenario.

> The number of solutions if we were to ignore the upper bounds is, as you mention, $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{13}{3}$.  In the case that one of the upper boundary conditions is violated, say for example, the upper bound for $y_1$, then that would imply that $y_1\geq 9$.  Go through a change of variable again to arrive at $$\begin{cases}w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4=2\\ 0\leq w_1\\ 0\leq w_2\\ 0\leq w_3\\ 0\leq w_4\end{cases}$$
>
> Conclude then how many of the $\binom{13}{3}$ choices are invalid because it violated the first upper bound.  Do so similarly for those which violate the second upper bound or third or fourth.  In inclusion-exclusion, we would then need to add back the number which violate two upper bounds simultaneously, and then subtract again those which violate three simultaneously, etc... however as mentioned earlier, you cannot have two upper bounds violated and still have the total sum be $11$.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting stuck because of an erroneous concept, you made my thinking clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using generating function:
Consider
$$(x+x^2+...+x^9)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^9)^3$$
open it and find out the coefficient of $x^{11}$

Comment: Some explanation would probably be required here...

Comment: Also, this assumes that $209$, e.g., is a four-digit number.  That may be (it depends on the OP's definition of four-digit number), but if it isn't, the approach has to be modified somewhat.

Comment: Indeed.  The OP did specify that the first digit be nonzero.  Technically, then, it could be corrected as $(x+x^2+\dots+x^9)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^9)^3$

Comment: @JMoravitz You are absolutely right, I modified the answer.